# Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType when using native images

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-native

I'm using Spring Boot 3 with WebFlux. Tests run successfully, local service also works fine. Problems appear when running native image generated by `gradlew bootBuildImage`.

Code example:

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfiguration {

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(GetWordsHandler getWordsHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                              .GET("/api/words/", getWordsHandler)
                              .build();
    }

}

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GetWordsHandler implements HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> {

    private final WordsService wordsService;

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return wordsService.getWords()
                           .flatMap(wordsResponse -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                   .bodyValue(wordsResponse))
                           .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
}

public record WordsResponse(List<String> words) {
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=com.example.WordsResponse
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:391) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ? Handler in.solomk.dictionary.api.handler.AddWordHandler@531fc147 [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ? org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ? org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ? HTTP POST "/api/words" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:391) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$writeWithMessageWriters$11(BodyInserters.java:381) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:381) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromPublisher$4(BodyInserters.java:185) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse.writeToInternal(DefaultEntityResponseBuilder.java:233) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$AbstractServerResponse.writeTo(DefaultServerResponseBuilder.java:343) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.support.ServerResponseResultHandler.handleResult(ServerResponseResultHandler.java:94) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.doHandleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:209) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:192) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handleRequestWith$6(DispatcherHandler.java:184) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:6.0.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxConcatMap.java:479) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2268) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2268) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2304) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2178) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:997) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:680) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$ChildObserver.onStateChange(ServerTransport.java:477) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:573) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:1.1.0]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:1.1.0]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:220) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:1.1.0]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:4.1.85.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:na]
        at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775) ~[in.solomk.dictionary.DictionaryApplication:na]
        at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203) ~[na:na]
```

Similar issue on GitHub, but there's no such classes: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/1721

Spring Boot version 3.0.0. Project mostly generated with Spring Initializer.

Answer (score 0):

While writing my question I've found solution to this problem and decided to share with others.

Spring Native requires hints where to use reflection.

Use `@RegisterReflectionForBinding(WordsResponse.class)` to specify that DTO requires reflection.

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0/reference/html/core.html#aot-hints-register-reflection-for-binding

I've used it in the handler to put it close to the place where I create response.

```
    @Override
    @RegisterReflectionForBinding(value = WordsResponse.class)
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return wordsService.getWords()
                           .flatMap(wordsResponse -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                   .bodyValue(wordsResponse))
                           .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
```